# Multiple a column by one field from another table in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I am a teacher using SQLite to manage my grade book. I am new to databases and programming in general.

I have two tables. One shows the students and the grades for a test and an essay.

```
Student table

student| Test | Essay 
--------------------
Skudd  | 50   | 10
Jim    | 25   | 11
```

The other shows the "out of mark" and the seemester weight.

```
Assessment Table

Assessment | Out_of | weight |
-----------------------------
Test       |   50   |    60  |
Essay      |   15   |    40  |
```

I want to create a view that will take each students grade for the test from the student table and divide by the out_of mark from the assessment table to calculate a percentage.

like this

```
New View

Student | Test | Essay |
--------|------|-------|
Skud    | 100  |  66   |
Jim     | 50   |  73   |
```

How do I multiple/divide by a single value from the assessment table(test field) to multiple records in the student grades table

Answer (score 0):

Just look up the values with a subquery:

```
SELECT Student,
       Test / (SELECT Out_of
               FROM Assessment
               WHERE Assessment = 'Test'
              ) AS Test,
       Essay / (SELECT Out_of
                FROM Assessment
                WHERE Assessment = 'Essay'
               ) AS Essay
FROM Student;
```

It's also possible to join the tables, but that's usually not done for such single-value lookups:

```
SELECT Student,
       Test  / Test_Ass.Out_of,
       Essay / Essay_Ass.Out_of
FROM Student
JOIN Assessment AS Test_Ass  ON Test_Ass.Assessment  = 'Test'
JOIN Assessment AS Essay_Ass ON Essay_Ass.Assessment = 'Essay';
```

Comment: works like a charm, thanks so much. There seems to be a difference between "Test" and 'Test'. I had no idea quotes types make a difference.